# Convert symbolic expression into a rational polynomial

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have a lengthy symbolic expression that involves rational polynomials (basic arithmetic and integer powers). I'd like to simplify it into a single (simple) rational polynomial.

`numden` does it, but it seems to use some expensive optimization, which probably addresses a more general case. When tried on my example below, it crashed after a few hours--out of memory (32GB).
I believe something more efficient is possible even if I don't have a cpp access to matlab functionality (e.g. `children`).

Motivation: I have an objective function that involves polynomials. I manually derived it, and I'd like to verify and compare the derivatives: I subtract the two expressions, and the result should vanish.
Currently, my interest in this is academic since practically, I simply substitute some random expression, get zero, and it's enough for me.

I'll try to find the time to play with this as some point, and I'll update here about it, but I posted in case someone finds it interesting and would like to give it a try before that.

To run my function:

```
x = sym('x', [1 32], 'real')
e = func(x)
```

The function (and believe it or not, this is just the Jacobian, and I also have the Hessian) can't be pasted here since the text limit is 30K:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1imOAa4VS87WDkOwAK0NoFCJPTK_2QIRj

Comment: At a glance, it looks like simplifying is not the goal? And I am assuming you ended up with a symbolic expression because you needed to use some other tool that output symbolic expression? Then maybe string process the formula in your file? You probably tried calling `numden` in several steps?

Comment: Simplifying into a rational poly is the goal, although here the specific application is for it to vanish. The motivation of the application is purely to prove without doubt that the derivatives are correct. Instead of string-processing from scratch, I suggested using children(). No, I didn't have time to experiment, and it would take a while until I do--when my academic interest would become practical. Maybe someone on the matlab team would take note and improve numden.

Comment: I see. Personally, I am reluctant to go to Matlab's symbolic package or any others. Doesn't scale well. So I just don't expect to be able to make my time worthwhile doing it. For handling poly, I'd rather only have the computer deal with coefficients -- which, I understand, is only practical if you don't need to keep track of fractions but can accept numeric (decimal) approximations in the coefficients.